# Using Axios to fetch data from Google Maps API and got Access-Control-Allow-Headers is not allowed error

Tags: javascript, axios

I tried to solve this for days.

I'm attempting to use the data from Google Maps API for my web application; therefore, I made the request like this:

```
axios.get('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=(user's location)&result_type=sublocality_level_1&key=(mykey)')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

Instead of getting objects on my console, I got this error:

```
Failed to load (the url): Request header field Accepts is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I have tried to config my header by using axios.defaults.headers to allow it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is this a Node.js application ?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but if you are still looking for an answer you need to download the [plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors/dboaklophljenpcjkbbibpkbpbobnbld?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)

It will allow you Cross Origin access from client side.

Comment: 1. The link is broken.

Comment: 2. This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question.